# PHP Convert 2 strings into binary, compare the differences and save differences

Tags: php, binary, string-comparison

Is there any way/function to compare differences between 2 binary strings (eg. 1 from a variable string and 1 from a file), and only re-save those differences back into either the variable string or file?

Eg.

01010000 01001000 01010000 00100000 01100001 01110010 01100101 00100000 01100111 01101111 01101111 01100100 00100001

PHP are good!

and

01010000 01001000 01010000 00100000 01101001 01110011 00100000 01100111 01101111 01101111 01100100 00100000 01101101 01100001 01101110 00100001

PHP is good man!

the command to compare the differences will pick up "are"/ "is" and " man"

and ONLY these differences will be re-saved into either the variable string or file like so

01010000 01001000 01010000 00100000 [del]01100001 01110010 01100101[/del][ins]01101001 01110011[/ins] 00100000 01100111 01101111 01101111 01100100 [ins]00100000 01101101 01100001 01101110[/ins] 00100001

PHP [del]are[/del][ins]is[/ins] good[ins] man[/ins]!

Another Example:

01010000 01001000 01010000 00100000 01100001 01110010 01100101 00100000 01100111 01101111 01101111 01100100 00100001

PHP are good!

01010000 01001000 01010000 00100000 01110100 01101000 01100101 00100000 01100111 01101111 01101111 01100100 00100001

PHP the good!

and what will be saved will be the difference between them which is "are/the"
so it becomes

01010000 01001000 01010000 00100000 [del]01100001 01110010 01100101[del][ins]01110100 01101000 01100101[/ins] 00100000 01100111 01101111 01101111 01100100 00100001

PHP [del]are[/del][ins]the[/ins] good!

Sorry if it looks messy. I didn't want to use the codebox to prevent the binary from being partially seen and for easier comparison

Comment: I disagree with you. similar_text simply calculates the similarity and to quote from your sources "Returns the number of matching chars in both strings."

levenstein only calculates the total number of changes but doesn't return them back to you. 

strcmp() works in a similar way as similar_text and levenstein combined.

What I'm looking for are differences that can be returned and save similar to array_diff in php but for string instead and these differences can be saved.

Comment: strcmp() can be used, but it still doesn't answer the question of how you can save that difference into the variable string or file AND remove the discrepancies.

Comment: way to go @Loz Cherone ツ, downvoting this without any reason and just deleting your comment making me look like i'm talking to myself

Comment: I not downvote it. see +1, also my comment was wrong and wanted to answer.

Answer (score 1):

If im understanding correctly, you want to have [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) behaviour on two strings, ok then just [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) them into an arrays, there is no need to base2 them before (if the source is base2 then convert it back).

But from your expected output you wont get what you want from [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) alone.

Your need to use [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) into [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to return what's different.

**Here is the user function:**

```
<?php
function str_diff($stringA='', $stringB='')
{
    $arrayA = explode(' ', $stringA);
    $arrayB = explode(' ', $stringB);

    //What I think you want
    return array_diff(
        array_merge($arrayA, $arrayB),
        array_intersect($arrayA, $arrayB)
    );

    //There's also this, but A has priority over B
    //return array_diff($arrayA, $arrayB);

    //And this returns just all unique, not compared
    //return array_unique(array_merge($arrayA, $arrayB));
}
?>
```

**Example A**

```
<?php
$strA = "PHP are good!";
$strB = "PHP is good man!";

$diff = str_diff($strA, $strB);

/*
Array
(
    [1] => are
    [2] => good!
    [4] => is
    [5] => good
    [6] => man!
)
*/
echo '<pre>'.print_r($diff, true).'</pre>';
//are good! is good man!
echo implode(' ', $diff);
?>
```

**Example B**

```
<?php 
$strA = "PHP are good!";
$strB = "PHP the good!";

$diff = str_diff($strA, $strB);

/*
Array
(
    [1] => are
    [4] => the
)
*/
echo '<pre>'.print_r($diff, true).'</pre>';
//are the
echo implode(' ', $diff);
?>
```

The saving of the string would be a trivial call to [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Firstly, I would like to apologise for the misunderstanding. I hope you can forgive me. Anyway, converting it to base2 is for better accuracy, as the method that you gave accounts for characters which splits using a whitespace. But what happens if you have something like "abcdefghi" and "abcdetghi"?